# Why doesn't a question with a close vote appear in the close review queue?

Tags: support, bug

[This question](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/q/4614/5961) currently has a vote to close. Why doesn't it appear in the close review queue?

Comment: It doesn't appear for you? Have you tried using a different device/network?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Definitely appears for me. I think the review queues icon at the top only gets an indicator on it when there's a certain number of pending reviews? And I'm not sure if there's a lag between when a flag is posted and when it shows up in the queue (there could be a scheduled process that populates the queue).

[image]

[image]

Comment: If it shows up for you, I won't worry about it, but it does not show for me still. Perhaps a factor is my voting to close this question in 2017.