# Shouldn't this question about area-specific training be closed as off-topic?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close

About the same question talked about [here](https://martialarts.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/622/why-doesnt-a-question-with-a-close-vote-appear-in-the-close-review-queue).

This question is asking for help looking for a school in one area. Isn't that specifically off-topic? It also looks like both attempts to answer it have been downvoted, so I'm not sure if it's really worth keeping open.

Answer (score 2):

While we have always had the rule about questions that were too localized, this question dates from a time on this site when the rules weren't as enforced. This is a normal phenomena - at a point in time members rediscover questions from an earlier period and question why on Earth it isn't closed. This has happened several times in the lifetime of the sister site StackOverflow and has resulted in several question purges.

But when I say *"rules weren't as enforced"*, I must emphasize that is a position taken by the community as a whole - a slightly more lenient attitude was important in the early days due to low traffic volume.

With regard to the question currently: you have to consider what is "too localized"? India is a large country with a massive population (roughly 2.5-3x the population of the USA). Additionally, even though the question uses some subjective terms, it is still ultimately quite a specific question.

While I am not advising either way whether the question should be closed, the above is some guidance on what should be considered before casting a vote.

I hope that answers your question about how that question still exists, and how the community should evaluate whether it needs to be closed.

Comment: Maybe it should just be locked, similar to other questions from before some rules were enforced?

Comment: @LemmyX Locking is more severe than closing because closed questions can still be edited for reopening but locked questions cannot. If the community cannot decide the question should be closed, it should definitely not be locked.

Comment: Oh, is there a way to protect it without the deprecation of locking it?

Comment: @LemmyX a question can be protected by anyone with sufficient rep, but the purpose of that is to prevent spammy or low quality answers. The question only needs one more close vote, so it shouldn't be long if others are also interested in closing it.